# ESQL Return New ID After Insert

Tags: sql, embedded-sql

I am trying to retrieve the new ID generated after a SQL insert using ESQL. I'm having problems figuring out the proper syntax or how to use the two UUID functions and could use a little assistance.

Comment: Which DBMS?  It matters.

Comment: I thought esql was the DBMS ;) BBj is the language I'm developing in, so it looks like the [Basis DBMS](http://www.basis.com/database-management).

Comment: ESQL normally stands for 'Embedded SQL', and is often tagged with the language it is embedded in (ESQL/C, ESQL/Cobol, ESQL/Fortran, ESQL/Ada, etc). And then you find that although there's an ISO standard (9075:2011) that includes ESQL, different DBMS implement different variants on the standard, with varying degrees of fidelity to the standard, often depending in part on how long ago the ESQL was first created (so products that existed before the SQL standard have greater divergence than those created after the SQL standard, in general). I've no useful information about the Basis DBMS — sorry!